# Rails get multiple values from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, hash

I'm trying to retrieve multiple values from a database into a single variable and return the whole thing.  Here is what I am doing

```
my_hash = {
  'name' => 'John'
  'current_location' => 'Sweden'
}
```

Now I need to go into database and retrieve all records and store them into a single variable, and then i need to add that variable into my_hash so I can return the whole thing.  How would I do that?

Example:

```
last_names = Names.where('first_name = ?', 'John').select('last_name').last_name
my_hash.add(last_names)
return my_hash
```

Now that above does not works, can somebody tell me proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you trying to do the following?

```
my_hash = {
  'name' => 'John'
  'current_location' => 'Sweden'
}

my_hash['last_names'] = Names.where('first_name = ?', 'John')
  .select('last_name')
  .map { |name| name.last_name } 
# or shorthand version .map(&:last_name)

return my_hash
```

Updated

```
# get name objects from the database 
# add select as an optimization if desired
last_name_list = Names.where('first_name = ?', 'John')
# get an array of only the last_name fields
last_names = last_name_list.map { |name| name.last_name }
# assign the array to the new hash key 'last_names'
my_hash['last_names'] = last_names
```

see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-map for documentation on map, note that map and collect are the same

another example

```
names = Names.where('updated_at >= ?', Date.parse('2013-01-01'))

# get an array of 'full names'
full_names = names.map do |name| 
  "#{name.first_name} #{name.last_name}"
end
```

Comment: I am new to ruby so forgive me but I do not understand that last line of code you have: .map.  I have no idea what that does.  I should probably add that select statement will return 3 values at minimum.

Comment: updated with more examples, might help clarify? `map` returns an array by iterating over elements in an existing array (which you are getting from the db in this case)

Comment: Thank you, that helped me quite a lot, especially the shorthand version.  Could you answer me one more thing though, how do I list all the values in a single paragraph from last_name array from your example above.  Would I do something along the lines of: my_hash['last_names'][0] ?

Comment: `my_hash['last_names'][0]` will return the 1st last_name in the array - i don't know what you mean by "list all the values in a single paragraph" - maybe `my_hash['last_names'].join(', ')` or using a rails helper `my_hash['last_names'].to_sentence` = "Frank, Fred and Joe" - http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence